# print out all strings between $ and *+2 characters in python

Tags: python, regex, string

i want to print out all substring in a string that has the following pattern +2 characters:
for example get the substrings

```
$iwantthis*12
$and this*11
```

from the string;

```
$iwantthis*1231  $and this*1121
```

in the monent i use

```
 print re.search('(.*)$(.*) *',string)
```

and i get `$iwantthis*1231` but how can i limit the number of characters after the last pattern symbol * ?

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [13]: s = '$iwantthis*1231  $and this*1121'

In [14]: re.findall(r'[$].*?[*].{2}', s)
Out[14]: ['$iwantthis*12', '$and this*11']
```

Here,

- `[$]` matches `$`;
- `.*?[*]` matches the shortest sequence of characters followed by `*`;
- `.{2}` matches any two characters.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
data = "$iwantthis*1231  $and this*1121"
print re.findall(r'(\$.*?\d{2})', data)
```

**Output**

```
['$iwantthis*12', '$and this*11']
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-QM_9c9XIY2TT26F)

[RegEx101 Explanation](http://regex101.com/r/zX1hW0)